# Stack Exchange site for discussing site implementation details

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a Stack Exchange site to answer questions about site implementation details. Not necessarily a technical scope, but more of a feature best-practices scope.

For example:

- Questions on how to monetize a free site
- How to handle deleting accounts without impacting site content

I know Stack Overflow is not appropriate as that is about code. I thought about Programmers, but I'm thinking that is still more on the technical side.

Comment: Might want to rephrase the question, as discussions aren't suitable for any Stack Exchange site (except for the *chat* of a certain site, and it's meta, when the discussion is about the governance of that site).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like http://webmasters.stackexchange.com might be a fit:

> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for **professional and enthusiast webmasters**. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect **entire websites**.

As always, check the [site FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) first, and take a look at their tags and questions to see if there is indeed a fit. Also, avoid 'discussion' questions (no shopping lists or opinion polls). Keep your questions answerable!